# Sqoop Import using remote java client

Tags: java, hadoop, ipc, sqoop

I am writing a remote java client for sqoop(1.4.5) import from mysql to HDFS(hadoop-1.2.1).

This is my code:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.set("fs.default.name","hdfs://x.y.z.w:8020");
config.set("mapred.job.tracker", "x.y.z.w:9101");
SqoopOptions options = new SqoopOptions(config);
options.setConnectString("jdbc:mysql://x.y.z.w:3306/testdb");
options.setUsername("user");
options.setPassword("password");
options.setTableName("test");
options.setTargetDir("/testOut");
options.setNumMappers(1);
int ret = new ImportTool().run(options);`
```

I am getting the following error:

`ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:xxx cause:java.net.UnknownHostException: unknown host: xxxx
ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.net.UnknownHostException: unknown host: xxxx
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.<init>(Client.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1239)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1093)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.checkVersion(RPC.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createNamenode(DFSClient.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:281)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:245)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1446)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1464)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:263)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:103)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:942)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:936)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:550)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:580)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runJob(ImportJobBase.java:119)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:413)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager.importTable(MySQLManager.java:97)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:381)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:454)`

The hadoop logs show the following:

namenode log:

`INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 8020: readAndProcess threw exception java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer. Co
unt of bytes read: 0
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer`

jobtracker log:

`INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 9101: readAndProcess threw exception java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer. Co
unt of bytes read: 0
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer`

Can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Issue can be with hostname not being resolved properly, check your hostname. 
Also check if you have given privilages to the specific hostname and user you are using in sqoop to import from Database.

Comment: Hi Karthik.. Thank you for taking time to answer.
I think it is able to resolve the IP into correct hostname and it is reaching the namenode and jobtracker.... as every time I run the code, a new info log(the ones mentioned in my question) is logged into both namenode and jobtracker loggers. And it is also able to query from the Database cause the java file corresponding to sqoop import is generated. Can you think of something else... Is it something about this java file being created on the remote machine?